# SVN diff - option ' --summarize '

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, summarize

Whenever I use

```
svn diff --summarize
```

I get something like :

```
A        *mylinkhere*
M        *mylinghere*
```

What are those beginning letters (eg A, M) for?

Comment: A is for added : the file has been added. M is for modified: the file has been modified.

Comment: Yeah, you're right!
I spent some time using `diff` without `--summarize` and compared the result. D is also for deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After comparing the result of `svn diff` with the result of `svn diff --summarize` I found out that :

- `D  - deleted`
- `A  - added`
- `M  - modified`
- `MM - file content modified & svn properties modified`

There where also a couple of 2M's ( `MM` ) which I still do not know what they stand for, but if I'll do, I'll come back and modify the answer.

@LaurentH. thanks for your help.

Comment: MM is for "file content modified" (first M) and "svn properties modified" (second M)